# eventpreventDefault() not working I need to show the results on same page

Tags: java, jquery, html

I have added the java script file in the html for a form and it is connected to the java file I want to show data on same page after submit i.e index.html but after the submission it takes me to the register page.

```html
html>
    <head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <title>Register form</title>
 </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="register">
        Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
        Email ID:<input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
        Password:<input type="text" name="pass" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#register").bind('submit',(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();

      /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
      var $form = $( this ),
          url = $form.attr( 'action' );

      /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
      var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val(),pass: $('#pass').val() } );

      /* Alerts the results */
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert('success');
      });
    });
</script>
        </form>
    </body>
 
 
 
</html>
```

Comment: it should be `$("#register").bind('submit',function(event) {` and try to look in the console I think an error will occur.. and add an id in your form.. `<form method="post" action="register" id="register">`

Comment: @ShadowFiend it is showing an error -Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Comment: then the `jquery` is not loaded..are you sure the path or the link  is correct ?

Comment: not sure about the path

Comment: why not sure? your code above loads the `jquery` but there is an error of an excess `(` in the code.

Comment: excess of ( where ?@ShadowFiend

Comment: here `$("#register").bind('submit',(function(event) {` change it to `$("#register").bind('submit',function(event) {`..

Comment: Its still not working please help@ShadowFiend

Answer (score 0):

The forms needs an id in order to be called with the query selector `#register`.

```
<form method="post" action="register" id="register">
```